# Bolding, spacing and indenting text in phpWord

Tags: php, phpword

I have some text that I want bold, separated from previous and subsequent paragraphs, and indented. 
I can't get all three properties to work together.

This works for bold and spaced:

```
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->addText(
    'Re: Your Application for Post of Security Guard',
    array('bold' => true),
    array('space' => array('before' => 360, 'after' => 280))
  );
```

and this works for indented:

```
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->addText(
    'Re: Your Application for Post of Security Guard',
   array('indentation' => array('left' => 540, 'right' => 120))
   );
```

but this doesn't work:

```
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->addText(
    'Re: Your Application for Post of Security Guard',
    array('bold' => true),
    array('space' => array('before' => 360, 'after' => 280)),
    array('indentation' => array('left' => 540, 'right' => 120))
  );
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm guessing there aren't any phpWord experts out there today.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The section addText function is:

```
$section->addText($text, [$fontStyle], [$paragraphStyle]);
```

i.e. the right way is to combine your paragraph styles into one array:

```
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->addText(
    'Re: Your Application for Post of Security Guard',
    array('bold' => true),
    array(
        'space' => array('before' => 360, 'after' => 280), 
        'indentation' => array('left' => 540, 'right' => 120)
    )
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, ejuhjav. That's great!