# How to make content restriction in phpword?

Tags: php, phpword

I am having trouble in making my content look like [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pY7z.png) this I am not using table also, how can I make my content in a certain space, not on full page.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: Here's an example of [how to set space and indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40671173/3986005).